# Keyboard not working on Ubuntu 14.10 Live CD

Tags: keyboard, 14.10, hardware

My system is Lenovo Idea-pad Notebook running Windows 7 Ultimate. I want to switch over to Ubuntu 14.10 and tried it with Ubuntu LiveCD. On the Try Ubuntu mode the keyboard is not working. What can I do?

Comment: What kind of keyboard is it? Internal, USB, or PS/2? For USB we need the output of `lsusb` to determine the responsible device driver.

Comment: Laptop keyboard. S10-3C.

Comment: This is an old, unfixed kernel bug ([Launchpad bug #677633](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/677633)). There's a workaround in [comment #111](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/677633/comments/111).

Comment: The workaround is for disabling your laptop keyboard. And now my problem's changed, I have a clean, nothing HDD and I'm trying to install Ubuntu onto it but all I get is a blinking cursor after I select "Install Ubuntu" in the installer. I've tried nomodeset and others but it just doesn't work.

Comment: If your question is now obsolete, please delete it. Find a question that suits your current situation or open a new question for it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Even if I manage, the problem will remain. I need a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research this issue is resolved through a [BIOS upgrade](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-U-and-S-Series-Notebooks/IdeaPad-S-Series-Latest-BIOS-Map/td-p/237096) ([direct link to file](http://download.lenovo.com/UserFiles/Driver/en/Downloads%20and%20Drivers/S10-3c/BIOS/3CCN16WW/txt%20update/3CCN16WW.exe)). Unfortunately many people seem to have issues to run this update even with the recommended Windows 7, but this can be resolved by placing an older AMI flashing driver `amifldrv32.sys` in the same folder ([source](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-U-and-S-Series-Notebooks/Not-able-to-run-3CCN16WW-bios-update/m-p/638061/highlight/true#M20379)). I found the whole package on a [Russian Linux enthusiast page](https://syslinux.ru/node/1321): https://syslinux.ru/sites/default/files/Lenovo_BIOS_Update.zip

Comment: Flashing of American Megatrend BIOSes can only be done with an OS installed. I have an empty HDD onto which I cannot install Ubuntu.

Comment: You need to complain to the manufacturer, that they only support Windows and don't even try to provide alternatives. You may be able to extract the BIOS image from the executable archive and flash it with a DOS program running inside FreeDOS. https://www.google.com/search?q=lenovo+ideapad+flash+bios+dos

Comment: Good answer!  Nothing that I can add to...  (and an upvote!)